# Permission with empty emailAddress

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-workspace

I have one member in a team drive that was suspended, but now it is active.
When I list permissions:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/{drive-id}/permissions?supportsTeamDrives=true&useDomainAdminAccess=true&fields=permissions(type%2Crole%2CemailAddress)
```

I get:

`{
 "permissions": [
  {
   "type": "user",
   "emailAddress": "",
   "role": "organizer"
  },
  {
   "type": "user",
   "emailAddress": "***@***",
   "role": "reader"
  }
 ]
}`

Is this a correct behavior to return an empty 'emailAddress' for users that were suspended? How can I get user mail in this case?

Comment: Did you try re-adding him using [Permissions.create](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/permissions/create)?

Comment: The user actually can access the team drive, all I want is to identity the users in that drive, it actually in this case gives user display name, but you can create users with same last and first name, so mail is the only way